# Size of coefficients in a logistic regression with Binary dependent variable

Tags: logistic, interpretation, regression-coefficients, binary-data

I am a very basic user and I am gonna ask a very simple question about the size of the coefficients in a logistic analysis.

I have run a logistic regression to analyse the probability of an event occurring in a panel of 30 countries with around 1000 obs. I have a binary dependent variable and four regressors.
I got the row coefficients, which I then transformed to get the ORs and to interprete them. (ok with this).

Based on the same dataset, I have run a second analysis. This second analysis uses the same  4  independent variables but the binary dependent variable is now wider. The binary variable still captures the (same types of) events but the definition I have used to identify them allows to include  more events occurring. So the binary dependent variable has a greater number of events compared to the first regression (say nearly double).
The row coefficients (and the ORs) that I got using this wider dependent variable are smaller compared to the first regression. So (I would say that) the contribution of the regressors to the probability of the event occurring is lower.

My question is very basic... How to interpret this? Is it normal that coefficients of the second regression (which use a greater number of events) are lower than the coefficients I got from the first regression?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I cannot understand how one binary dependent variable in a logistic regression could be "wider" than another, because the values used to encode the variable are irrelevant.  Could you explain what this means?

Comment: It sounds like you have *redefined* your variable.  That suggests there is no reason to suppose there would be any relationship between the two logistic regressions.

Comment: ... and that's why your question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

With fewer events, it's easier for predictors to perfectly predict or come close to perfectly predicting the outcome, which implies larger coefficients. It's often a good idea to correct the bias in your logistic regressions using a Firth correction, which is especially helpful with smaller samples and fewer events. The unadjusted logistic regression coefficients are known to be (sometimes badly) biased.

Comment: Thank you. I will go for it!